# Checked/Unchecked Dynamically Populates/Unpopulates Textarea

Tags: checkbox, textarea

I'm trying to use checkboxes to populate a textarea with certain text; however, when the checkbox is unselected, I'd like to have the populated text deleted. I've tried this:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
var tb = "#"+$(this).attr('rel');
if($(this).is(":checked"))
$(tb).append(this.name + "\n"); 
else($(this).not(":checked"))
$(tb).remove(this.name + "\n");
});
```

to no avail. Halp?

EDIT
**Major** step forward... I've figured-out how to redesign the script to **almost** do exactly what I need. I altered the above to this:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
var tb = "#"+$(this).attr('rel');
if($(this).is(":checked"))
$(tb).append(this.name + "\n")
else($(tb).empty(this.name + "\n"))
});
```

My only problem now is that when I uncheck a checkbox, it clears **all** text from the textbox, when I only want it to clear the **specific** text which corresponds to the unchecked checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code it will help you....

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>                     

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    $('#purchased').html($('#purchased').val() + $(this).attr('name') + "\n");
else
{
    var text = $('#purchased').val();
    text = text.replace($(this).attr('name') + "\n" ,"");
    $('#purchased').html(text);
}
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="purchased" cols="25" rows="10"></textarea>
        <p>Pennsylvania State Standards, Subject 1: Reading, Writing, Speaking, and Listening</p>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" rel="textbox" name="1.1. Reading Independently">1.1. Reading Independently</input></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" rel="textbox" name="1.2. Reading, Analyzing, and Interpreting Text">1.2. Reading, Analyzing, and Interpreting Text</input></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" rel="textbox" name="1.3. Reading, Analyzing, and Interpreting Literature: Fiction and Non-Fiction">1.3. Reading, Analyzing, and Interpreting Literature: Fiction and Non-Fiction</input></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" rel="textbox" name="1.4. Types of Writing">1.4. Types of Writing</input></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" rel="textbox" name="1.5. Quality of Writing">1.5. Quality of Writing</input></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" rel="textbox" name="1.6. Speaking and Listening">1.6. Speaking and Listening</input></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" rel="textbox" name="1.7. Characteristics and Functions of the English Language">1.7. Characteristics and Functions of the English Language</input></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" rel="textbox" name="1.8. Research">1.8. Research</input></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" rel="textbox" name="1.9. Information, Communication, and Technology Literacy">1.9. Information, Communication, and Technology Literacy</input></li>
        </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is too simplistic for what I need done; I have 54 checkboxes, each with different text to be populate/unpopulated in the textarea. Is my script messed-up in the "else" command?

Comment: Brilliant! When I copy yours over it works **exactly** how I want it to; however, when I blend your code into my formatting--e.g., having the textarea in a relatively positioned div--it doesn't work at all. Eh? Also, how would I add either a line break or a ", " to each of the standards being populated?

Comment: Never mind, I figured that out. When I copy yours over it works **exactly** how I want it to. I noticed you use an "older" version of jquery (1.8.3), not 1.9.0; any reason why? I **did** notice when I tried your script with 1.9.0 it didn't work.

Comment: i think you also used the same version ... so only i tried by that

Comment: Nope, I used the 1.9.0; wonder what changed between the two that one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: i have updated my code to jquery 1.9.0... Try the new one.... Fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/j2UXX/2/